# Downloading a video form amazon s3 using laravel 5 PHP

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How do I download a video file form my amazon s3 bucket?

I have followed the docs but cannot figure it out. I have set up my amazon details in laravel, and when tyring to dwonload the file i get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundException in File.php line 37:
The file "https://s3.ireland.amazonaws.com/my-bucket-name/Shoots/2016/06/first%20video%20shoot/videos/high.mp4" does not exist

public function s3Test()
{
$url = Storage::url('Shoots/2016/06/first video shoot/videos/high.mp4');
return response()->download($url);
}
```

The $url looks like this: https://s3.ireland.amazonaws.com/my-bucket-name/Shoots/2016/06/first%20video%20shoot/videos/high.mp4

Is this the correct way to go about downloading an amazon s3 file?

**Edit::**
when trying to change permissions to everyone i get the error:

```
S3Exception in WrappedHttpHandler.php line 192:
Error executing "ListObjects" on "https://s3.ireland.amazonaws.com/thevirtualwebsite?prefix=high.mp4%2F&max-keys=1&encoding-type=url"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 6: Couldn't resolve host 's3.ireland.amazonaws.com' (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

Comment: Does `high.mp4` have read permissions to everyone ? Can you download it from your browser without being authenticated on s3 ?

Comment: @PedroLobito I have set it to everyone but now i get the following error message , update din my question

Comment: `s3.ireland.amazonaws.com` does **not** exist, check the correct url to your file.

Comment: ive just done dd(Storage::disk('s3')->get('high.mp4')); and get the following error Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 225411432 bytes)

Comment: I guess you found the answer.